# Marking a position and a route on an image

Tags: javascript, html

Im developing a new wayfinding piece of software. Im thinking of having the user select a background image a overview of a amusement park, office facility or the like. Then having the user select a number of important points on the image. E.g. "you are here" point where the "monitor" containing the wayfinder map is (this will change eventually and be more dynamic).

So the deal is:

1: Need to be web based
2: Having the administrator select a point on an image
3: Having the administrator map out a series of destinations (points) on the image
4: Layout/draw the lines between the source point and the end points.

**How to select/click a point on an image in HTML5 and get the coordinates (x,y)** of that point? (i suppose i can use the same technology for drawing/mapping out the routes on the image.

All input is appreciated,

/Brian

Comment: you can look at this one, http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1929-how-to-use-the-canvas-and-draw-elements-in-html5/ is really good to get the location and event of the pointer,

Comment: also here is another example in how to do that http://jsbin.com/ApuJOSA/1/edit

Comment: and each time the cursor moves, put those values in anther function which sets and get the values of coordinates, and when you click you just get those values and do what you need with them, you know what i mean ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `<canvas style="background-image:url(map.jpg)" id="map">` tag. Then you can use `context =  document.getElementById('map').getContext("2d");` to create a `context`, `context` have the line drawing functions.

You can get the x,y coordinates via and of the`onlick`, `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events.